# Be a member of TPC of a low quality conference

Tags: conference, reputation, program-committee

Recently I have recieved few emails from conference organisers to become a member of conference technical program committee. Three of them are international conferences and going to held in China and Thailand. 
I am a fresh PhD is it good to participate in low quality conferences as TPC member? 
 it will have a positive or negative impact in my resume?

Comment: I get spam emails like this several times per week. Often, these conferences are in China and often they are very broad. Just delete and forget them.

Answer (score 14):

I strongly suspect that these are fake conferences, ultimately designed to scam you, other researchers and/or grant agencies for money. Any voluntary association with such events is a sign that you are rather clueless as an academic, and should be avoided.

There, however, plenty of small, very specialized conferences with high acceptance rates. These serve more as meetings and get-togethers for their research community than as highly respected publication venues. Being asked to serve on the TPC here is essentially a statement by your community that you are a respected member of this community, and would be a nice addition to the CV of a recent graduate.

Answer (score 4):

> I am a fresh PhD is it good to participate in low quality conferences as TPC member?

No. It is *never* good to associate yourself with unreputable people and activities. Your reputation is determined by the things you do and organizations and people you associate with. If you want to attain high reputation, only get involved in reputable projects.

> it will have a positive or negative impact in my resume?

Negative. To me, activities like this on a resume signal someone with poor judgment, and/or who doesn't have more impressive activities to report, neither of which are good.

Comment: It might be hasty to jump from "low quality" to "disreputable". While I agree that the OP probably is talking about a disreputable event, there are obviously events which are reputable, but amongst the reputable events, of comparatively low quality.

Comment: @Arno well, disreputable simply means "not having a good reputation". Thus, to my mind a low quality conference is by definition disreputable.